# Why NSMutableArray literal assignment don't work correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Something strange happened to me today.

I have a NSMutableArray array

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *draggedWords;
```

Then I assign null values to the array (someElements has 4 elements)

```
[someElements enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomLabel *element, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // ...
    self.draggedWords[idx] = [NSNull null];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", self.draggedWords);
```

Then in another action of the same controller, I do replace a value in the array (index == 0)

```
self.draggedWords[index] = self.draggableItem;
NSLog(@"%@", self.draggedWords);
```

The result is actually really strange. Instead of replacing the value at index, it's adding it:

```
2014-02-14 14:21:44.601 [39271:70b] (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
2014-02-14 14:21:49.870 [39271:70b] (
    "<CustomLabel: 0x19156b40; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (374 0; 300 80); text = '...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x191d0960>>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

If I use replaceObjectAtIndex instead, it works as expected

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:Object];
```

I get what I expected (4 elements)

```
2014-02-14 14:25:24.670 [39271:70b] (
    "<CustomLabel: 0x19156b40; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (374 0; 300 80); text = '...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x191d0960>>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

Why on earth is this happening? 
I expected the same behaviour.

Comment: I doubt that what you're saying is true.  It is possible to get a "confused" array, where (due to improper storage management) some of the elements address nonexistent objects.  This can result in bizarre behaviors.

Comment: (And you should probably use the term "assignment".  "Assignation" has an entirely different connotation to most English-speakers.)

Comment: I doubt your result too as my test is different with yours. pls show your code

Answer (score 4):

Minimal test case:

```
NSMutableArray *foo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], nil];
NSLog(@"%@", foo);
foo[0] = @"bar";
NSLog(@"%@", foo);
```

Output:

```
2014-02-14 14:27:15.083 test[6642:70b] (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
2014-02-14 14:27:15.084 test[6642:70b] (
    bar,
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

So the behavior you're describing does not come from Cocoa. Please show your code.

**EDIT**:

Again, impossible to reproduce the problem with what you gave:

```
NSArray *someElements = @[@1, @2, @3, @4];

NSMutableArray *draggedWords = [NSMutableArray array];
NSLog(@"%@", draggedWords);
[someElements enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    draggedWords[idx] = [NSNull null];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", draggedWords);

draggedWords[0] = @"bar";
NSLog(@"%@", draggedWords);
```

Output:

```
2014-02-14 17:03:07.427 test[15380:70b] (
)
2014-02-14 17:03:07.429 test[15380:70b] (
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
2014-02-14 17:03:07.429 test[15380:70b] (
    bar,
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

Something is wrong in some other part of your code. Try to identify which part is giving you this weird output by commenting your code bits by bits until the bug disappear.

Comment: That's what I would expect, but it's happening something different. I've updated the question with the lines of actual code that I've in my application.

Comment: I'm not mutating the same object that I'm enumarating on. I'm enumerating on someElements, while editing self.draggedWords (with the index of someElements. It's not the same thing.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see that. I updated my answer again.

Comment: So, we've tried to run the same code on 3 different machines (altough, always in the simulator...). Before today, it never happened. And checking the code revision system, we've not touched nothing related for weeks. Maybe a sort of bug...

Comment: Maybe Clean + Clean build folder + Buid ?

Comment: Already tried. And especially I've tried to compile on 3 different macs. Same result

Answer (score 0):

You're confused somehow. This code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"zero", @"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
array[0] = @"new one";
NSLog(@"array = %@", array);
```

Gives this result:

```
array = (
    "new one",
    one,
    two,
    three
)
```

That clearly shows that the item at index 0 is replaced with the "new one".

Comment: That's what I would expect, but it's happening something different. I've updated the question with the lines of actual code that I've in my application.